# How does Annotation @Autowire for interface instantiate in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have seen many examples of Spring boot wherein we declare an interface which extends crudrepository and declare the CRUUD methods. Post which in Service CLass we autowire the interface and invoke the crud methods from Service class.

Since we are not implementing this interface(which extends CrudRepo in example PersonRepo ) anywhere ,how come spring instantaties it ?
Ex :

```
    interface PersonRepo extends CRUDRepository {
    // method declaration
    }

    @Service
    class PersonService{
    @Autowire
    PersonRepo perrepo;

    void insert(){
    perrepo.methodname();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring introduces [dynamic proxy](http://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies).
In fact it scans package and get all interfaces which extend Crud Repository interface. For each of them a Dynamic Proxy instance is created. On each call the proxy checks which method is called and uses appropriate annotation. The proxies are used as beans so can be autowired.